# Simplest choice to store INT's & Strings locally and persistently in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save a few important values to my IOS app, that can be accessed from anywhere inside the app and stay there persistently. No network connection should be required. The values are mostly INT's and one or two strings. What is the simplest method of accomplishing this?

Comment: You can use Userdefaults http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend UserDefaults. The most simple and minimal code approach is to create a global variable as opposed to using a singleton approach like this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

You can then, from anywhere within the app access these defaults like this:

```
defaults.set(12, forKey: "HighScore")
```

You have now set the property with key "HighScore" to 12. To retrieve the property that associates with the key "HighScore" you simply write:

```
defaults.integer(forKey: "HighScore")
```